# Duvidas de como rederizar ordenado e organizadamente array em v-for

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js

Possuo um *array* a partir desse *JSON*:

```
[{
    "cod_recurso": 36,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Aceita Animais de Pequeno Porte",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 4,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Diferencial"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 5,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Aceita Reserva",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 6,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Adega",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 3,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Ambiente Climatizado",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 20,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "American Express",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 2,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Cart\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 35,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Apartamento com Facilidades para Dificientes F\u00edsicos",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 4,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Diferencial"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 40,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Ar condicionado",
    "icone": "rec_5c1239d074457781207415.jpeg",
    "ref_cod_categoria": 5,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": "2018-12-13 08:52:00.457911",
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": 43,
    "categoria": "Equipamento"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 9,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Atendimento Bil\u00edngue",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 49,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Banheira de Hidromassagem",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 5,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Equipamento"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 26,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Banri Compras",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 2,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Cart\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 11,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Bar",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 48,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Cama Box Springs",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 5,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Equipamento"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 25,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Cielo",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 2,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Cart\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 47,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Cofre",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 5,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Equipamento"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 1,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Com Acesso para Deficientes F\u00edsicos",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 22,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Credicard",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 2,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Cart\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 39,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Delivery - Servi\u00e7o de Entrega",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 4,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Diferencial"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 21,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Diners",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 2,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Cart\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 27,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Elo",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 2,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Cart\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 7,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Espa\u00e7o para Eventos",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 2,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Estacionamento Pr\u00f3prio",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 32,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Green Card",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 3,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Vale Refei\u00e7\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 24,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Hipercard",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 2,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Cart\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 4,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Internet Sem Fio",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 17,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Maestro",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 2,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Cart\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 18,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Master Card",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 2,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Cart\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 8,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Mesas ao Ar Livre",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 51,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Mesas ao Ar Livre",
    "icone": "rec_5c361f8b769fb423686765.jpeg",
    "ref_cod_categoria": 4,
    "data_cadastro": "2019-01-09 14:21:31.467237",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 43,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Diferencial"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 50,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Mini-bar",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 5,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Equipamento"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 38,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "M\u00fasica ao Vivo",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 4,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Diferencial"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 33,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Personal Card",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 3,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Vale Refei\u00e7\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 15,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Piscina",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 16,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Piscina T\u00e9rmica",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 37,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Pr\u00f3ximo a Praia",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 4,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Diferencial"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 52,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Recurso para testar redimensionamento",
    "icone": "rec_5c3637deb822d500021585.jpeg",
    "ref_cod_categoria": 4,
    "data_cadastro": "2019-01-09 15:10:27.906647",
    "data_exclusao": "2019-01-09 16:05:18.726302",
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 43,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": 43,
    "categoria": "Diferencial"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 23,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Rede Shop",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 2,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Cart\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 10,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Restaurante",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 13,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Sala de Gin\u00e1stica",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 12,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Sala de Jogos",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 1,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Estrutura"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 45,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Sala para Acesso Internet",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 5,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Equipamento"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 34,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Senff",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 3,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Vale Refei\u00e7\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 29,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Sodexo",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 3,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Vale Refei\u00e7\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 44,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Som",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 5,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Equipamento"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 42,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "TV",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 5,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Equipamento"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 43,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "TV a Cabo",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 5,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Equipamento"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 41,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Telefone",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 5,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Equipamento"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 31,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Ticket",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 3,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Vale Refei\u00e7\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 28,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "VR Alimenta\u00e7\u00e3o",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 3,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Vale Refei\u00e7\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 19,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Visa",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 2,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Cart\u00e3o"
}, {
    "cod_recurso": 30,
    "ativo": 1,
    "nome": "Visa Vale",
    "icone": null,
    "ref_cod_categoria": 3,
    "data_cadastro": "2018-11-19 10:44:19.24543",
    "data_exclusao": null,
    "ref_cod_usuario_cad": 1,
    "ref_cod_usuario_exc": null,
    "categoria": "Vale Refei\u00e7\u00e3o"
}]
```

Preciso imprimir o valor do índice `nome` em uma lista, separado por sua respectiva categoria e sem repeti-la.

Exemplo (imagem feita como modelo e exemplo):

[image: só um exemplo feito no paint, atualmente o código só gera as categorias]

Meu código, até então, que gera dinamicamente as categorias e as imprime:

```
    <template>
    <div v-if="place"
        id='app-place-modal'
        style='position: absolute; float: left; left: 30%; top: 10%; width: 40%; height: 40%; background-color: #FAFAFA; border-radius: 15px'
    >
        <button @click="closeModal()"  type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <br>

        <p>Nome: {{ placeModal.nome }}</p>
        <p>Descrição: {{ placeModal.descricao }}</p>
        <p>Endereço: {{ placeModal.logradouro }} {{ placeModal.numero }}</p>
        <p>Horário de atendimento: {{ placeModal.horario }}</p>
        <p>Telefone: {{ placeModal.telefone_1 }}</p>
        <p>Email: {{ placeModal.email }}</p>
        <p>Site: {{ placeModal.site }}</p>
        <div class="d-flex p-2">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Recursos</legend>
                <ul>
                    <li v-for='category in category'>
                        <h6> {{category}} </h6>
                        <li :key="(recurso.cod_estabelecimento, recurso.cod_categoria)"
                            v-for='recurso in recursos'>
                         </li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex p-2">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Fotos</legend>
                <img
                        :key='image'
                        style='width: 20%;'
                        v-for='image in placeModal.fotos'
                        :src='getImageURI(image)'
                />
            </fieldset>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Config from '@/config'
import Http from '@/services/Http'
import Bus from '@/bus'
import Axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'app-modal',
  data () {
    return {
      placeModal: Array,
      recursos: Array,
      category: Array,
      categoriaFilter: Array,
      id: ''
    }
  },
  props: {
    place: Object
  },

  created () {
    Http.getOne(this.place.cod_estabelecimento)
      .then(response => {
        this.placeModal = response.data
        this.recursos = this.placeModal.recursos
        this.id = this.placeModal.cod_estabelecimento
        console.log(this.placeModal + ' created')
        this.organizeCategory()
        return this.$forceUpdate()
      })
  },
  mounted () {
    Bus.$on('make-modal', value => {
      Http.getOne(value.cod_estabelecimento)
        .then(response => {
          this.placeModal = response.data
          this.recursos = this.placeModal.recursos
          this.id = this.placeModal.cod_estabelecimento
          console.log(this.placeModal + ' mounted')
          this.organizeCategory()
          return this.$forceUpdate()
        })
    })
  },

  methods: {
    getImageURI () {
      return Config.API_BASE_PATH.concat('foto/estabelecimento?id=', this.id)
    },
    getRecurso () {
      let recurso = this.placeModal.recursos[2].cod_recurso
      this.recursos = Axios.get(Config.API_BASE_PATH.concat('recurso?id=', recurso))
      console.log(this.recursos)
      return this.recursos
    },
    closeModal () {
      Bus.$emit('close-modal', true)
    },
    organizeCategory () {
      var recursos = this.placeModal.recursos
      var categoria = []
      for (var i = 0; i < recursos.length;) {
        categoria.push(recursos[i].ref_cod_categoria)
        i++
      }
      var categoriaFilter = categoria.filter((elem, index, categoria) => categoria.indexOf(elem) === index)
      this.categoriaFilter = categoriaFilter

      var categories = []
      for (i = 0; i < categoriaFilter.length;) {
        if (categoriaFilter[i] === 1) {
          categories.push('Estrutura')
        }
        if (categoriaFilter[i] === 2) {
          categories.push('Cartão')
        }
        if (categoriaFilter[i] === 3) {
          categories.push('Vale Benefício')
        }
        if (categoriaFilter[i] === 4) {
          categories.push('Diferencial')
        }
        if (categoriaFilter[i] === 5) {
          categories.push('Equipamento')
        }
        i++
      }

      this.category = categories
      console.log(categories)
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Como trazer os valores do índice `nome` e jogar na categoria certa, como se fizesse uma condição `where`?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui!!! Foi colocada um v-if para fazer a condição. Segue o código com a solução:

```
    <template>
    <div v-if="place"
        id='app-place-modal'
        style='position: absolute; float: left; left: 30%; top: 10%; width: 40%; height: 40%; background-color: #FAFAFA; border-radius: 15px'
    >
        <button @click="closeModal()"  type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <br>

        <p>Nome: {{ placeModal.nome }}</p>
        <p>Descrição: {{ placeModal.descricao }}</p>
        <p>Endereço: {{ placeModal.logradouro }} {{ placeModal.numero }}</p>
        <p>Horário de atendimento: {{ placeModal.horario }}</p>
        <p>Telefone: {{ placeModal.telefone_1 }}</p>
        <p>Email: {{ placeModal.email }}</p>
        <p>Site: {{ placeModal.site }}</p>
        <div class="d-flex p-2">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Recursos</legend>
                <ul>
                    <li :key="categoria.cod_categoria" v-for='categoria in category'>
                        <h6> {{categoria}} </h6>
                        <span :key="(recurso.cod_estabelecimento, recurso.cod_categoria)"
                            v-for='recurso in recursos'>
                            <span v-if="recurso.categoria === categoria">{{recurso.nome}}</span>
                         </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex p-2">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Fotos</legend>
                <img
                        :key='image'
                        style='width: 20%;'
                        v-for='image in placeModal.fotos'
                        :src='getImageURI(image)'
                />
            </fieldset>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Config from '@/config'
import Http from '@/services/Http'
import Bus from '@/bus'
import Axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'app-modal',
  data () {
    return {
      placeModal: Array,
      recursos: Array,
      category: Array,
      categoriaFilter: Array,
      id: ''
    }
  },
  props: {
    place: Object
  },

  created () {
    Http.getOne(this.place.cod_estabelecimento)
      .then(response => {
        this.placeModal = response.data
        this.recursos = this.placeModal.recursos
        this.id = this.placeModal.cod_estabelecimento
        console.log(this.placeModal + ' created')
        this.organizeCategory()
        return this.$forceUpdate()
      })
  },
  mounted () {
    Bus.$on('make-modal', value => {
      Http.getOne(value.cod_estabelecimento)
        .then(response => {
          this.placeModal = response.data
          this.recursos = this.placeModal.recursos
          this.id = this.placeModal.cod_estabelecimento
          console.log(this.placeModal + ' mounted')
          this.organizeCategory()
          return this.$forceUpdate()
        })
    })
  },

  methods: {
    getImageURI () {
      return Config.API_BASE_PATH.concat('foto/estabelecimento?id=', this.id)
    },
    getRecurso () {
      let recurso = this.placeModal.recursos[2].cod_recurso
      this.recursos = Axios.get(Config.API_BASE_PATH.concat('recurso?id=', recurso))
      console.log(this.recursos)
      return this.recursos
    },
    closeModal () {
      Bus.$emit('close-modal', true)
    },
    organizeCategory () {
      var recursos = this.placeModal.recursos
      var categoria = []
      for (var i = 0; i < recursos.length;) {
        categoria.push(recursos[i].ref_cod_categoria)
        i++
      }
      var categoriaFilter = categoria.filter((elem, index, categoria) => categoria.indexOf(elem) === index)
      this.categoriaFilter = categoriaFilter

      var categories = []
      for (i = 0; i < categoriaFilter.length;) {
        if (categoriaFilter[i] === 1) {
          categories.push('Estrutura')
        }
        if (categoriaFilter[i] === 2) {
          categories.push('Cartão')
        }
        if (categoriaFilter[i] === 3) {
          categories.push('Vale Benefício')
        }
        if (categoriaFilter[i] === 4) {
          categories.push('Diferencial')
        }
        if (categoriaFilter[i] === 5) {
          categories.push('Equipamento')
        }
        i++
      }

      this.category = categories
      console.log(categories)
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

saída:

[image: só falta formatar]

agora só falta estilizar e formatar!

Obrigado.